# Simple route will not match

Tags: regex, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I can't see what's wrong with this route in CakePHP.

`http://www.example.com/board/app-max` will not match.

Here is my route

```
Router::connect(
    '/board/:key',
    array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'board'),
    array('key'=>'[a-z\-]+')
);
```

I end up with a `BoardController` not found error.

`http://www.example.com/board/app` matches succesfully. So my problem is when `key` contains a dash.

**EDIT:** I've found that `[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+` works fine, but `[a-z\-]+` does not.

### Setup Details

- PHP 5.4.16
- CakePHP 2.4.1
- Windows 7
- Zend Community Server 6.1

### .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect non-www urls to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Rewrite rule for CakePHP
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What's your exact CakePHP version? Also what kind of server software are you using? And what does your `.htaccess` look like, any rewrite rules that could interfer?

Comment: @ndm so I found that `[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+` works fine but `[a-z\-]` does not. I'm using Cake 2.4.1 on Windows with PHP 5.4.16

Comment: Weird. Try to debug `lib\Cake\Routing\Route\CakeRoute.php`, put this in the `parse()` method, right before the `preg_match()` call: `pr(h($this->_compiledRoute) . PHP_EOL . h(urldecode($url)));` This should show you the exact regex that is applied on the exact URL fragment (you could also use a [custom route class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes) for debugging purposes).

Comment: Try `[-a-z]` or `[a-z-]`, as `-` should not be escaped if is first or last...

Comment: @Ωmega Why and under which circumstances would an unnecessarily escaped `-` cause problems?

Comment: @ndm - Should NOT, but it looks like OP is facing some not standard behavior

Comment: @Ωmega I can not explain it, but it appears that the problem has gone away. I can no longer reproduce the problem. So strange.